# Android: How to implement drawing on top of image

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-canvas

The goal is to be able to write / sketch /draw anything on top of the image taken and also erase without destroying the image making the image remain intact, and when saving the image the drawing and the image at the background would be included in the final output.

I have built an app that takes a photo then sends it to a new activity for preview and editing where I should be able to draw over the image like a circle or some lines. I was able to do this by creating the bitmap and passing it through the new Canvas() constructor.

The problem with this is I could write on the image but when I use the erase mode the image also gets erased, I'd like to implement something that would let me erase without destroying the background image, and at the same time the image on the background would still be included when I save the image finally.

The code for my View is below.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawingView extends View {

    //drawing path
    private Path drawPath;
    //drawing and canvas paint
    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
    //initial color
    private int paintColor = 0xFF660000, paintAlpha = 255;
    //canvas
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    //canvas bitmap
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    //brush sizes
    private float brushSize, lastBrushSize;
    //erase flag
    private boolean erase=false;

    Bitmap bg;

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        setupDrawing();
    }

    //setup drawing
    private void setupDrawing(){

        //prepare for drawing and setup paint stroke properties
        brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
        lastBrushSize = brushSize;
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        Resources res = getResources();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.background);
        bg = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    }

    //size assigned to view
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(bg);
    }

    //draw the view - will be called after touch event
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bg, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    }

    //register user touches as drawing action
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        //respond to down, move and up events
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                drawPath.reset();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        //redraw
        invalidate();
        return true;

    }

    //update color
    public void setColor(String newColor){
        invalidate();
        //check whether color value or pattern name
        if(newColor.startsWith("#")){
            paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
            drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
            drawPaint.setShader(null);
        }
        else{
            //pattern
            int patternID = getResources().getIdentifier(
                    newColor, "drawable", "com.example.drawingfun");
            //decode
            Bitmap patternBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), patternID);
            //create shader
            BitmapShader patternBMPshader = new BitmapShader(patternBMP,
                    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
            //color and shader
            drawPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            drawPaint.setShader(patternBMPshader);
        }
    }

    //set brush size
    public void setBrushSize(float newSize){
        float pixelAmount = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                newSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        brushSize=pixelAmount;
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    }

    //get and set last brush size
    public void setLastBrushSize(float lastSize){
        lastBrushSize=lastSize;
    }
    public float getLastBrushSize(){
        return lastBrushSize;
    }

    //set erase true or false
    public void setErase(boolean isErase){
        erase=isErase;
        drawPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        if(erase) drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        else drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    }

    //start new drawing
    public void startNew(){
        drawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        invalidate();
    }

    //return current alpha
    public int getPaintAlpha(){
        return Math.round((float)paintAlpha/255*100);
    }

    //set alpha
    public void setPaintAlpha(int newAlpha){
        paintAlpha=Math.round((float)newAlpha/100*255);
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAlpha(paintAlpha);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java is this

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.UUID;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    //custom drawing view
    private DrawingView drawView;
    //buttons
    private ImageButton currPaint, drawBtn, eraseBtn, newBtn, saveBtn, opacityBtn;
    //sizes
    private float smallBrush, mediumBrush, largeBrush;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //get drawing view
        drawView = (DrawingView)findViewById(R.id.drawing);

//        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
//            drawView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background, null));
//        }
//        else
//            drawView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
        //get the palette and first color button
        LinearLayout paintLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.paint_colors);
        currPaint = (ImageButton)paintLayout.getChildAt(0);
        currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));

        //sizes from dimensions
        smallBrush = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.small_size);
        mediumBrush = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
        largeBrush = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.large_size);

        //draw button
        drawBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.draw_btn);
        drawBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        //set initial size
        drawView.setBrushSize(smallBrush);

        //erase button
        eraseBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.erase_btn);
        eraseBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        //new button
        newBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.new_btn);
        newBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        //save button
        saveBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        //opacity
        opacityBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.opacity_btn);
        opacityBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //user clicked paint
    public void paintClicked(View view){
        //use chosen color

        //set erase false
        drawView.setErase(false);
        drawView.setPaintAlpha(100);
        drawView.setBrushSize(drawView.getLastBrushSize());

        if(view!=currPaint){
            ImageButton imgView = (ImageButton)view;
            String color = view.getTag().toString();
            drawView.setColor(color);
            //update ui
            imgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));
            currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint));
            currPaint=(ImageButton)view;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){

        if(view.getId()==R.id.draw_btn){
            //draw button clicked
            final Dialog brushDialog = new Dialog(this);
            brushDialog.setTitle("Brush size:");
            brushDialog.setContentView(R.layout.brush_chooser);
            //listen for clicks on size buttons
            ImageButton smallBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.small_brush);
            smallBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    drawView.setErase(false);
                    drawView.setBrushSize(smallBrush);
                    drawView.setLastBrushSize(smallBrush);
                    brushDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            ImageButton mediumBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.medium_brush);
            mediumBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    drawView.setErase(false);
                    drawView.setBrushSize(mediumBrush);
                    drawView.setLastBrushSize(mediumBrush);
                    brushDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            ImageButton largeBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.large_brush);
            largeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    drawView.setErase(false);
                    drawView.setBrushSize(largeBrush);
                    drawView.setLastBrushSize(largeBrush);
                    brushDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            //show and wait for user interaction
            brushDialog.show();
        }
        else if(view.getId()==R.id.erase_btn){
            //switch to erase - choose size
            final Dialog brushDialog = new Dialog(this);
            brushDialog.setTitle("Eraser size:");
            brushDialog.setContentView(R.layout.brush_chooser);
            //size buttons
            ImageButton smallBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.small_brush);
            smallBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    drawView.setErase(true);
                    drawView.setBrushSize(smallBrush);
                    brushDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            ImageButton mediumBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.medium_brush);
            mediumBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    drawView.setErase(true);
                    drawView.setBrushSize(mediumBrush);
                    brushDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            ImageButton largeBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.large_brush);
            largeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    drawView.setErase(true);
                    drawView.setBrushSize(largeBrush);
                    brushDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            brushDialog.show();
        }
        else if(view.getId()==R.id.new_btn){
            //new button
            AlertDialog.Builder newDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            newDialog.setTitle("New drawing");
            newDialog.setMessage("Start new drawing (you will lose the current drawing)?");
            newDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    drawView.startNew();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            newDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            newDialog.show();
        }
        else if(view.getId()==R.id.save_btn){
            //save drawing
            AlertDialog.Builder saveDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            saveDialog.setTitle("Save drawing");
            saveDialog.setMessage("Save drawing to device Gallery?");
            saveDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    //save drawing
                    drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    //attempt to save
                    String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                            getContentResolver(), drawView.getDrawingCache(),
                            UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png", "drawing");
                    //feedback
                    if(imgSaved!=null){
                        Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Drawing saved to Gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        savedToast.show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast unsavedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Oops! Image could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        unsavedToast.show();
                    }
                    drawView.destroyDrawingCache();
                }
            });
            saveDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            saveDialog.show();
        }
        else if(view.getId()==R.id.opacity_btn){
            //launch opacity chooser
            final Dialog seekDialog = new Dialog(this);
            seekDialog.setTitle("Opacity level:");
            seekDialog.setContentView(R.layout.opacity_chooser);
            //get ui elements
            final TextView seekTxt = (TextView)seekDialog.findViewById(R.id.opq_txt);
            final SeekBar seekOpq = (SeekBar)seekDialog.findViewById(R.id.opacity_seek);
            //set max
            seekOpq.setMax(100);
            //show current level
            int currLevel = drawView.getPaintAlpha();
            seekTxt.setText(currLevel+"%");
            seekOpq.setProgress(currLevel);
            //update as user interacts
            seekOpq.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    seekTxt.setText(Integer.toString(progress)+"%");
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

            });
            //listen for clicks on ok
            Button opqBtn = (Button)seekDialog.findViewById(R.id.opq_ok);
            opqBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    drawView.setPaintAlpha(seekOpq.getProgress());
                    seekDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            //show dialog
            seekDialog.show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you had the right idea at one point; setting the image as the background. Did that not work for you?

Comment: @MikeM. it doesn't work for me :(, the background just renders all white if I do use that method.

Comment: How do you mean? It's white even when you're drawing, or just when you try to save it?

Comment: It is white upon first loading the view, screenshot of the view when setbackground used : [link](http://screencast.com/t/ck9pgvbkmn) ,

Comment: What is `R.drawable.background`, exactly? I mean, what's the image, and how big is it? With your code as it is right now, that image should be loaded at its intrinsic size, and drawn in the upper left corner of your `DrawingView` when it's initialized. If you were to uncomment the `drawView.setBackground()` block in the `Activity`, it should be sized to fit the whole `View`, and set as the background. Are you sure `background` is what you're thinking it is?

Comment: This is the image specifically on 1980 x 1000 https://www.pexels.com/photo/nature-white-cactus-97260/

Comment: OK, that image has huge blank areas. With your code now, it's going to be loaded and drawn at it's actual size, during the `DrawingView`'s initialization. It's quite possible that you just can't see the cactus, because it's drawing off-screen, and all you're seeing is the blank area in the upper left. I'd suggest you either try with a different image to test, or remove the `bg` `Bitmap` from `DrawingView` temporarily, and uncomment the `drawView.setBackground()` block. If it's set as the background, it'll be shrunk to fit the `View`, and you'll see it if it's there.

Comment: @MikeM. hey man, it now works with a smaller image. :O Can't believe it was just the issue, I have continued on setting the image as a background of the custom view, then when saving the image I'll just get the cacheddrawable which includes both the background and the drawing paths :D thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my problem was just to set the image as the background of the surfaceview via setBackgroundDrawable. Then upon saving it I just had to get the drawing cache from the canvas which then includes the background image.

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented all the things in right way, but i just want to suggest you to try out the following code, may be it would help you out.

```
public void clearCanvas() {
        drawPath.reset();
        invalidate();
}
```

try this method instead of setErase(), The above method is used to clear the path that you have created using touch. You can reset all values to default values in this method.

Comment: actually it's not about clearing the canvas, set erase in there is to set the brush to a color for erasing the paths on drag.

Comment: This will not erase the canvas actually, but it will clear the path that you have drawen.

Comment: Thanks for that info, that might be useful for undo.